# How to convert python code (.py) to an app on mac osx

Tags: python, macos, py2app, dmg

I am making an app in python, which is able to open different file types. This code is running fine on eclipse while passing filename which I want to open and configuration file as arguments respectively `selectedFileName=(sys.argv)[1]`
`cfgFile=(sys.argv)[2]`. Now I converted this into application by using py2app. So, the issue is how to deal with arguments, as different file types need to be open through app and this app also needs configuration file while processing. Through py2app, in  terminal passing this command `open -a myapp.app selectedFileName config.cfg` opens the file as expected. But, What I want is to directly open file of any extension without the use of terminal. Is `openwith` for opening file possible in this case, then how?. What changes I have to make in code for passing arguments for both? I also want to distribute this app to others.

Comment: try to look here http://blog.adamw523.com/os-x-cocoa-application-python-pyobjc/

Comment: I don't want any window to display. Its just an app to open a file. I have issues regarding passing arguments in app developed by py2app without the use of terminal. In windows, it can be solved with the help of registry file.No idea regarding this on mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use py2app. It makes a standard app. All it needs is a python script and setup.py.

Comment: If you also want to submit the app to the Mac App Store, you have to do some additional work: http://dafoster.net/articles/2014/06/24/submitting-a-python-app-to-the-mac-app-store/

Answer (score 3):

### [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

You might want to have a look at [Platypus](http://sveinbjorn.org/platypus). It's intended to create Mac .app bundles from shell scripts. The documentation has some [information on how to accept files](http://sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html#41) that looks like it should be applicable to you. I haven't tested it out, but you should be able to run your script by dropping files onto the icon, and possibly using the *Open With* menu as well.